# How to localstore and get value from TranslateX?

Tags: jquery, local-storage

Hello i have these piece of code :

```
var note = $('#just-a-slider .handle');

updatePosition(note);

new Dragdealer('just-a-slider', {
animationCallback: function(x, y) {
$('#just-a-slider .value').text(Math.round(x * 100));

        var left = note.position().left;
        localStorage.setItem("left", left);

        console.log(left);

}
});


   function updatePosition(note) {

    var left = localStorage.getItem("left");
    note.css({ transform: "translateX " +left + "px" });

    }
```

But it doesn't work for some reasons.

- The variable stored in left is good, and work if i write this :

  ```
  function updatePosition(note) {

  var left = localStorage.getItem("left");
  note.css({ left: left + "px" });

  }
  ```

  but not with :

  ```
  note.css({ transform: "translateX " +left + "px" });
  ```
- For exemple this code work :

  ```
  var left = 100; //or xx;
  note.css({ transform: "translateX " +left + "px" });
  ```

So if think "transform" is not compatible with localstorage ? Am i wrong ?

What's the solution ?
Thank you for the help.

(Sorry, i'm french)

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean? what happens when you log `"translateX " +left + "px"`, does it look correct? does the element get the transform effect in the property inspector?

Comment: I have no code error in the inspector, i have just nothing ! It look correct but when i reload, the console log is "0" for left and "translateX 0px" for "translateX " +left + "px"

Comment: so your saying the transform property is not applied to the element?

Comment: Yes, if after reload i get translateX(500px), the transform property is not applied. But it works with  left: left + "px"